# Output link under label

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to put link under label which will scroll down to the section down in the VF page. I am getting an Error

> Error Error: LeadDetail line 123, column 52: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference
>   Error   Error: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

```
 <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
    <apex:outputText value="D & B Company Name \<a name="#detailList"\>more...\</a\>" escape="true"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!RH_Lead__c.Company_Name1__c}"/>
</apex:pageblocksectionitem>
```

**detailList** is a section at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `&` with `&amp;` in the value attribute

EDIT: you need to replace all the reserved characters (&, <, > etc) with their named character entity reference ("escaped" values) in attributes, because the attributes are parsed - `<` needs to be `&lt;`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: Now getting The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "apex:outputText" must not contain the '<' character.

Comment: `<` needs to be `&lt;`

Comment: Thanks Brian. And how to make it auto scroll to thebottom.

Comment: That's a completely separate question, if you have another question you may ask it here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask